# Barwise exercise: nonprojectibles are recursively Mahlo

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In Barwise's *Admissible Sets and Structures*, there's an exercise to prove that every nonprojectible ordinal is recursively Mahlo. $\alpha$ is recursively Mahlo if every $\alpha$-recursive function $f:\alpha\to\alpha$ has a witness, and if $\textrm{KP}$ is the fragment of $\textrm{ZF}$ obtained by removing powerset and restricting replacement and separation both to $\Delta_0$ formulae, $\alpha$ is nonprojectible if $L_\alpha\vDash\textrm{KP}+\Sigma_1\textrm{-separation}$. ($\textrm{KP}$ may also omit infinity, depending on who you ask, in which case use $L_\alpha\vDash\textrm{KP+Infinity}+\Sigma_1\textrm{-separation}$.)

However I don't understand the $\Sigma_1$-separation characterization of nonprojectible ordinals, so instead I'm attempting to use Jensen's "strong $\Sigma_1$-collection schema":

- $\alpha$ is nonprojectible if $L_\alpha$ satisfies the schema $\forall u\exists v\forall(x\in u)(\exists y[\phi(x,y)]\implies\exists(y\in v)[\phi(x,y)])$ for all $\Sigma_1$ formulae $\phi(x,y)$ of two free variables. (R. Jensen, [The fine structure of the constructible hierarchy](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Elaiken/papers/FineStructure.pdf))

But this schema doesn't look very different from the usual $\Sigma_1$-collection, which I already know (as mentioned in [MO answer #137213](https://mathoverflow.net/a/137213)) is equivalent to $\Delta_0$-collection. I have failed to come up with an instance of strong $\Sigma_1$-collection that $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ fails - there must be one that it fails, since $\omega_1^{CK}$ is not nonprojectible.

I feel like if I know an instance of strong $\Sigma_1$-collection which $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ fails, the exercise will be easier. What is such an example?

---

Here are some attempts that I've tried:

- $\phi(x,y)$ iff $x$ and $y$ are ordinals, and $y=\omega^x$. But we can recover this from $\Sigma_1$-collection as well: as $\forall x\exists y\phi(x,y)$ holds in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, $\Sigma_1$-collection applies.
- $\phi(x,y)$ iff $y$ is the order type of the ordinal notation $x$ (as in Kleene's $\mathcal O$.) I'm not sure if there is such a $\Sigma_1$ formula, but even if there is one, $\exists y[\phi(x,y)]$ may be false in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ so the schema doesn't seem to imply closure under anything.
- $\phi(x,y)$ iff $x$ and $y$ are both ordinals, and $y$ is the least admissible ordinal $>x$. This is a $\Delta_0$-definable function according to Rathjen (["A Proof-Theoretic Characterization of the Primitive Recursive Set Functions"](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/PrimRec.pdf#page=16), p.968), and yet it seems like it *still* does not imply $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is closed under any operator in particular: if for some $x\in u$ we do not have a $y\in L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ such that $\phi(x,y)$, then the right-hand side $\exists(y\in v)\phi(x,y)$ need not be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second bulletpoint is exactly what you want, you just have to analyze it more carefully.

Note that strong $\Sigma_1$ collection does **not** require each element $x$ of the "source set" $u$ to actually have a corresponding $y$! (Put another way, strong $\Sigma_1$ collection is really $\Sigma_1$ collection where the source is an arbitrary $\Sigma_1$ sub*class* of some set.)

So take the formula $\varphi(x,y)\equiv$ "$x$ is an index for a computable linear order, $y$ is an ordinal, and $y$ is isomorphic to the linear order with index $x$. This is $\Sigma_1$, and when applied to this formula with $u=\omega$ the strong $\Sigma_1$-collection scheme would require the existence of a set containing every computable ordinal - and no such set exists in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. Note that this is really just "reversing" the fact that the $\Sigma_1$-projectum of $\omega_1^{CK}$ is $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks! I may review your answer later, until then I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants an answer to the Barwise exercise, someone told me recently an interesting method that I did not expect, it does not use strong $\Sigma_1$-collection. We know (e.g. [Math.SE question #4381934](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4381934)) that every nonprojectible ordinal $\beta$ has a cofinal sequence of ordinals $(\alpha_\xi)_{\xi<\lambda}$ below it, where for each $\alpha_\xi$ we have $L_{\alpha_\xi}\prec_{\Sigma_1}L_\beta$. We also know (e.g. [MO question #419900](https://mathoverflow.net/q/419900)) that $\beta$ is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on the set $\{\alpha_\xi\mid\xi<\lambda\}$.

The recursively Mahlos are exactly the ordinals $\Pi_2$-reflecting on the admissible ordinals, and each $\alpha_\xi$ is admissible. (The citation for both of these facts is Richter and Aczel's "[Inductive definitions and reflecting properties of admissible ordinals](https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/44063?show=full)".) So if we have a $\Pi_2$ formula $\phi(x)$ with parameter $x\in L_\beta$ where $L_\beta\vDash\phi(x)$, and we want to reflect $\phi(x)$ down to some $L_\alpha$ with $\alpha<\beta$, we can just choose one of the $\alpha_\xi$ where we have $x\in L_{\alpha_\xi}$, and by the $\Pi_2$-reflection property $\beta$ has on the $\alpha_\xi$ we will have $L_{\alpha_\xi}\vDash\phi(x)$ as desired. Since regardless of $\phi$ or $x$ we may choose an admissible ordinal $\alpha_\xi$,  $\beta$ is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on the admissibles, and recursively Mahlo.